# Borland Delphi 7 "Too many actual parameters" then resetting file

Tags: delphi, parameters, reset, pascal

It's throwing an "*Too many actual arguments*" compiling error at my face when resetting the file for reading.

When leaving out the "SaveFile" part from both the reset and the close parts, it's throwing a bunch of IO error 104's and 105's when executing.

What am I missing?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn3: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn4: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn5: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn6: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn7: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn8: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn9: TBitBtn;
    StaticText1: TStaticText;
    StaticText2: TStaticText;
    StaticText3: TStaticText;
    StaticText4: TStaticText;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Label7: TLabel;
    BitBtn10: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn11: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn12: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn13: TBitBtn;
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Label2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn6Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn7Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn8Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn9Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure winnerCheck;
    procedure Reset;
    procedure BitBtn10Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn11Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ReadFile;
    procedure WriteFile;
    procedure BitBtn12Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn13Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }


  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  total: Double;
  odd: Boolean;
  even: Boolean;
  Clicked1: Boolean;
  Clicked2: Boolean;
  Clicked3: Boolean;
  Clicked4: Boolean;
  Clicked5: Boolean;
  Clicked6: Boolean;
  Clicked7: Boolean;
  Clicked8: Boolean;
  Clicked9: Boolean;
  totalscore : Double;
  winnerX : Boolean;
  winnerO : Boolean;
  xwins : Double;
  owins : Double;
  Games : Double;
  Ties : Double;
  SaveFile : textfile;
  ln1,ln2,ln3,ln4,ln5 : String;
  lolol:Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked1=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn1.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn1.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn1.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn1.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn1.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn1.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn1.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn1.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn1.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn1.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked1:=true;
winnerCheck;
end;

end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked2=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn2.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn2.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn2.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn2.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn2.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn2.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn2.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn2.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn2.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn2.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked2:=true;
winnerCheck;
end;
end;

//procedure setTotal(Sender: TObject);
//Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
//end;


procedure TForm1.Label2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked3=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn3.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn3.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn3.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn3.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn3.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn3.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn3.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn3.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn3.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn3.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked3:=true;
winnerCheck;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked4=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn4.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn4.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn4.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn4.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn4.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn4.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn4.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn4.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn4.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn4.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked4:=true;
winnerCheck;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked5=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn5.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn5.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn5.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn5.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn5.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn5.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn5.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn5.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn5.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn5.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked5:=true;
winnercheck;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked6=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn6.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn6.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn6.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn6.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn6.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn6.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn6.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn6.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn6.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn6.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked6:=true;
winnerCheck;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked7=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn7.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn7.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn7.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn7.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn7.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn7.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn7.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn7.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn7.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn7.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked7:=true;
winnerCheck;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn8Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked8=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn8.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn8.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn8.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn8.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn8.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn8.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn8.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn8.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn8.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn8.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked8:=true;
winnercheck;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn9Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label2.Caption:=floattostr(total);
if Clicked9=false then
begin
if total=0 then BitBtn9.Caption:='X';
if total=2 then BitBtn9.Caption:='X';
if total=4 then BitBtn9.Caption:='X';
if total=6 then BitBtn9.Caption:='X';
if total=8 then BitBtn9.Caption:='X';
if total=1 then BitBtn9.Caption:='O';
if total=3 then BitBtn9.Caption:='O';
if total=5 then BitBtn9.Caption:='O';
if total=7 then BitBtn9.Caption:='O';
if total=9 then BitBtn9.Caption:='O';
if total>=9 then total:=0;
total:= total+1;
Clicked9:=true;
winnerCheck;

end;
end;
procedure TForm1.winnerCheck;
begin
if ((Clicked1=true) and (BitBtn1.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked2=true) and (BitBtn2.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked3=true) and (BitBtn3.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn1.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn2.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn1.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn2.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked1=true) and (BitBtn1.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked2=true) and (BitBtn2.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked3=true) and (BitBtn3.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn1.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn2.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn1.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn2.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked4=true) and (BitBtn4.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked6=true) and (BitBtn6.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn4.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn4.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked4=true) and (BitBtn4.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked6=true) and (BitBtn6.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn4.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn4.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked7=true) and (BitBtn7.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked8=true) and (BitBtn8.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked9=true) and (BitBtn9.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn7.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked7=true) and (BitBtn7.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked8=true) and (BitBtn8.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked9=true) and (BitBtn9.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn7.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked1=true) and (BitBtn1.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked4=true) and (BitBtn4.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked7=true) and (BitBtn7.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn1.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn4.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn1.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn4.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked1=true) and (BitBtn1.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked4=true) and (BitBtn4.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked7=true) and (BitBtn7.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn1.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn4.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn1.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn4.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked2=true) and (BitBtn2.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked8=true) and (BitBtn8.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn2.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn2.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked2=true) and (BitBtn2.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked8=true) and (BitBtn8.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn2.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn2.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn8.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked3=true) and (BitBtn3.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked6=true) and (BitBtn6.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked9=true) and (BitBtn9.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn3.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked3=true) and (BitBtn3.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked6=true) and (BitBtn6.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked9=true) and (BitBtn9.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn3.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn6.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked1=true) and (BitBtn1.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked9=true) and (BitBtn9.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn1.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn1.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked1=true) and (BitBtn1.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked9=true) and (BitBtn9.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn1.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn1.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn9.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked3=true) and (BitBtn3.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='X')) and ((Clicked7=true) and (BitBtn7.Caption='X')) then
begin
bitbtn3.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler X heeft gewonnen!');
winnerX:=true;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clblack;
end;
if ((Clicked3=true) and (BitBtn3.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked5=true) and (BitBtn5.Caption='O')) and ((Clicked7=true) and (BitBtn7.Caption='O')) then
begin
bitbtn3.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clgreen;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clgreen;
showMessage('Speler O heeft gewonnen!');
WinnerO:=true;
bitbtn3.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn5.font.color:= clblack;
bitbtn7.font.color:= clblack;
end
else if ((clicked1=true) and (clicked2=true) and (clicked3=true) and (clicked4=true) and (clicked5=true) and (clicked6=true) and (clicked7=true) and (clicked8=true) and (clicked9=true) and (WinnerX=false) and (WinnerO=false)) then
begin
Ties:= ties+1;
Label1.Caption:=floattostr(ties);
showmessage('Gelijk spel!');
reset;
end;
if WinnerO=true then
begin
owins:=strtofloat(Label7.Caption);
Label7.Caption:=floattostr(owins+1);
Reset;
end;
if WinnerX=true then
begin
xwins:=strtofloat(Label6.Caption);
Label6.Caption:=floattostr(xwins+1);
Reset;
end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Reset;
begin
BitBtn1.Caption:='';
BitBtn2.Caption:='';
BitBtn3.Caption:='';
BitBtn4.Caption:='';
BitBtn5.Caption:='';
BitBtn6.Caption:='';
BitBtn7.Caption:='';
BitBtn8.Caption:='';
BitBtn9.Caption:='';
total:=0;
Label2.Caption:='0';
WinnerX:=false;
WinnerO:=false;
Games:= Games+1;
Label3.Caption:=floattostr(Games);
Clicked1:=false;
Clicked2:=false;
Clicked3:=false;
Clicked4:=false;
Clicked5:=false;
Clicked6:=false;
Clicked7:=false;
Clicked8:=false;
Clicked9:=false;

end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn10Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Reset;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
reset;
label3.caption:='0';
label6.caption:='0';
label7.caption:='0';
label1.Caption:='0';
xwins:=0;
owins:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ReadFile;
begin
assignfile(SaveFile, 'SaveFile.txt');
{$I+} //to use exceptions
try
  System.Reset(SaveFile);
  Readln(SaveFile, ln1); //X
  Label6.Caption:=ln1;
  xwins:=strtofloat(ln1);
  Readln(SaveFile, ln2); //O
  Label7.Caption:=ln2;
  owins:=strtofloat(ln2);
  Readln(SaveFile, ln3); //Ties
  Label1.Caption:=ln3;
  ties:=strtofloat(ln3);
  Readln(SaveFile, ln4); //Amt Total
  Label2.Caption:=ln4;
  total:=strtofloat(ln4);
  Readln(SaveFile, ln5); //Amt Games
  Label3.Caption:=ln5;
  Games:=strtofloat(ln5);
  System.Close(SaveFile);
except
writeln('Doetniemeer');
end;

end;


procedure TForm1.WriteFile;
begin
assignfile(SaveFile, 'SaveFile.txt');
{$I+} //to use exceptions'n shit
try
  Rewrite(SaveFile);
  writeln(SaveFile, Label6.Caption); //Score X
  writeln(SaveFile, Label7.Caption); //Score O
  writeln(SaveFile, Label1.Caption); //Ties
  writeln(SaveFile, Label2.Caption); //Total Amount (1-9) Likely due to be 0 because... it just is
  writeln(SaveFile, Label3.Caption); //Amt. Games
  CloseFile(SaveFile);
except

on E: EInOutError do writeln('Doetniemeer '+E.Message);
end;

end;
procedure TForm1.BitBtn12Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
WriteFile;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn13Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ReadFile;
end;

end.




// if total>=9 then total:=0;
// if total=1 then odd:=true;
// if total=3 then odd:=true;
// if total=5 then odd:=true;
// if total=7 then odd:=true;
// if total=9 then odd:=true;
// if total=0 then even:=true;
// if total=2 then even:=true;
// if total=4 then even:=true;
// if total=6 then even:=true;
// if total=8 then even:=true;
// total:=total+1;
// if odd then BitBtn1.Caption:='X';
// if even then BitBtn1.Caption:= 'O';
```

Comment: is SaveFile a global variable?

Comment: Yes, it's waay up there with all the other vars so i assume it is (15 char minimal...)

Comment: It makes me sad that you've made all your variables global. I can't understand why you want us to guess what types all the variables are. It would also be better if you showed the exact error message and the line of code where it occurred.

Comment: Or why you are using old-style Pascal I/O instead of something more modern like `TStringList` or `TFileStream`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan All the variabled relevant to this code: `  totalscore : Double;
  winnerX : Boolean;
  winnerO : Boolean;
  xwins : Double;
  owins : Double;
  Games : Double;
  Ties : Double;
  SaveFile : textfile;
  ln1,ln2,ln3,ln4,ln5 : String;`

Comment: That's unreadable. The information needs to be in the question. A complete program is probably needed. Now your program. The cut down one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not sure, it was probably the first thing i'd seen, i'll look a bit further now

Comment: Your edit shows that Remy was correct. It's the only plausible explanation. But having the code makes us 100% certain.

Comment: Not related to the question, but while the code might end up doing what you want, it's "wrong" on many levels. If this is part of course work I'd recommend for your teacher to use this as a starting point to explain some basic patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because your Form has its own `Reset()` method that does not take any parameters:

```
procedure Reset;
```

The compiler is trying to call that method instead of the [`System.Reset()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Reset) function.

So either rename your `TForm1.Reset()` method to something else, or qualify the `Reset(SaveFile)` call with the `System.` prefix so the compiler knows which `Reset()` it needs to call.

Comment: @Leon And for future reference, the compiler told you exactly which line had the error. If you had right-clicked `Reset` on that line, and selected "Find declaration" from the pop-up menu: The IDE would have taken you to Reset on your form. This would have been the clue you needed to understand the problem yourself.